# Cover background-image with transparent background-color (full screen)

Tags: html, css, background, fullscreen

i want to cover my background image with transparent color,but the color doesn't cover the background image.

here is my demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/farna/73kx2/

css code:

```
.overlay{
    background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    margin: 0 ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: have you used opacity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [***LIVE DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/73kx2/2/)

all what you have to do to achieve this is to use [Pseudo-elements - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) on the body. 
Here i am using the `body:after`

**1. The Style:**

```
body{
    position:relative;
    background: url(http://8pic.ir/images/cgnd518gxezm1m2blqo7.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0
}
body:after{
    position:fixed;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    z-index:-1;
}
```

[image]

here is your HTML

**2. The Markup:**

```
<body>
      <div class="overlay">
          <nav>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">SHOP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">PRESS</a></li>
              </ul>
           </nav>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: fixed` to your css rule:

http://jsfiddle.net/73kx2/1/

Comment: Your answer is right but it seems the `ul` is here for navigation menu. and if we stretch it all over the page then no other sections will be visible on the page. It will be better to have a dummy element for this tinting effect.

Answer (score 1):

Add `height:100%` to your html and body. Update your CSS like below.

```
body, html{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
.overlay{
background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding:0;
}
ul{margin:0;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/73kx2/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Add position: fixed to the overlay:

```
.overlay{
    background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    margin: 0 ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/73kx2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated CSS

```
.overlay{
    background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    margin: 0 ;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

`height` in `100%` inherits from it's `parent`. So you have to add it to `body`, and `body's` **parent** `html` too.

But easiest way to create, cover overlay with `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; position: absolute | fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for optimal result

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            html,body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%
                margin: none;
                padding: none;
            }

            #background {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                z-index: -99999;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -khtml-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -o-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }

            #background img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #main{ z-index:10;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            content here
        </div>
        <div id="background"><img src="bg.jpg"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```